# Updating a progressbar with Caliburn Micro

Tags: multithreading, progress-bar, caliburn.micro

I keep reading how great Caliburn is at thread marshaling and how updating the UI thread is incredibly easy but I can't seem to get it to work nor can I find an example that shows it so I need help...

Here is my XAML...

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Label Content="Progress For Current File" />
    <WrapPanel>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="CurrentFileProgress" Width="500" Height="25" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" />
        <Label Content="1 of 25" />
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is my ViewModel...

```
public void Go()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(PathToFiles, "*.sql");

    CurrentFileProgress = 0;

    for (int iter = 1; iter <= files.Length; iter++)
    {
        CurrentFileProgress = iter / (files.Length * 1.0f);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);

    }
}

private double _CurrentFileProgress = 3; //For design time look

public double CurrentFileProgress
{
    get { return _CurrentFileProgress; }
    set
    {
        _CurrentFileProgress = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CurrentFileProgress);
    }
}
```

This is simple enough and after a few seconds my progress bar is at 100% but it doesn't step like I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that by calling Thread.Sleep you block the UI thread so the UI cannot be updated until the action is finished. 
Try to run the process on a background thread (or use TPL - Tasks).

Comment: I found the error in my ways late last night before reading your answer. The issue was that my for loop was on the UI thread and as soon as I put the for loop on a separate using TPL as you suggested it worked like a charm.